# The multi part identifier xxx could not be bound (Inner-Join)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, inner-join

I have created the following query:

```
SELECT vw.PackID AS NewData
FROM
(
    SELECT mt.PackID
    FROM EntityTable entities 
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MasterTable mt
        WHERE [Id] IN 
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 [chartID] FROM ChartTable
            Where [Code] IN
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 [Account] FROM ItemsTable it
                Where [EntityID] IN
                (
                    Select Distinct EntityID From EntityTable Where EntityID=@EntityID
                )
            )
        )
    ) mtbvw
    ON mt.Id = mtbvw.Id
) vw
```

I am a C# Developer and have barely touched SQL, so there is probably a better way to achieve this (With Inner Joins?) but I am getting the following errors:

> The multi-part identifier "mt.Id" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "mcoa.1" could not be bound.

Can anyone help as to why I am getting these errors?
Thank you! :)

A little bit of info regarding what this is doing:

> The EntityID is getting passed into the stored procedure. The Account is then taken from ItemsTable based on the EntityID passed in. The accuont is then passed to ChartTable which gives back the first ChartID (All the ChartID's are the same for that Account so takiing the top one will not matter) and same passing this ChartID back into the MasterTable and getting out the Main ID. Thanks :)

Comment: When you say vw.1 you are asking for the column named "1" which clearly doesn't exist here. As coded it is hard to figure out what this is trying to do. You have a number of top 1 queries here but no order by. With no order by you don't know which row will be returned.

Comment: And is this mysql or sqlserver or both? They are not the same thing.

Comment: @SeanLange This is sql server, sorry

Comment: @SeanLange The Account is taken from ItemsTable based on the EntityID passed in. The accuont is then passed to ChartTable which gives back the first ChartID (All the ChartID's are the same for that Account so takiing the top one will not matter) and same passing it back into the MasterTable and getting out the ID. Thanks :)

Comment: The error is because you can't reference a table inside a subquery from outside of it. The outer query can't "see" into the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess based on the query provided.

```
Select Distinct et.EntityID 
From EntityTable et
join ItemsTable it on it.EntityID = et.EntityID
join ChartTable ct on ct.Code = it.Account
join MasterTable mt on mt.Id = ct.charID
Where et.EntityID = @EntityID
```

Comment: I think you want `Select Distinct mt.PackId` here as per the question. Otherwise, why would all those joins even be necessary? Couldn't you simply use:  `Select Distinct EntityID from EntityTable Where EntityID = @EntityID`

Comment: @SeanLange I think the issue here is that I only want to join MasterTable, not ItemsTable or ChartTable? I only need to use those in order to get the correct MasterTable, but I can't do that without joining?